# Thymeleaf placeholder in input type="text"

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have this input text in a

```
<input type="text" id="usernameId"  name="username" placeholder="User" />
```

I want to replace the text of the placeholder User for 1 text from the properties file, but I don't know if it is possible

```
<input type="text" id="usernameId"  name="username" placeholder="th:text="#{user.placeholder}""  />
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is a specific Thymeleaf attribute for that:

```html
<input type="text" id="usernameId"  name="username" th:placeholder="#{user.placeholder}" />
```

It can also be written like this:

```
<input type="text" id="usernameId"  name="username" th:attr="placeholder=#{user.placeholder}" />
```

Comment: th:placeholder="${user.placeholder}" instead of th:placeholder="#{user.placeholder}" works

Answer (score 1):

In the above answer it should be

```
<input type="text" id="usernameId"  name="username" th:placeholder="${user.placeholder}" />
```

${...} operator is for using with objects in context such as request, session and objects set in model.

#{...} operator is for message expressions..

Check  [thymeleaf tags list](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-value-to-specific-attributes) and [thymeleaf doc](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#standard-expression-syntax) for details