# Thymeleaf placeholders - 0 instead of field description

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Trying to use placeholders to have description inside the field.

[image: expected result]

```
<div class="container">
    <form th:action="@{/loans/save}" th:object="${loan}" method="POST">
        <input type="text" th:field="*{salesPrice}"
               class="form-control mb-4 col-4" placeholder="First name">
    </form>
</div>
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thymeleaf placeholder in input type="text"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43810612/thymeleaf-placeholder-in-input-type-text)

Comment: @damianm https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-placeholder-attribute/

Comment: Why are you binding a field for first name to `*{salesPrice}`.  Sales price is probably an integer with a default value of 0.

Comment: I was binding first name to *{salesPrice} only as an example. But in this case you were very close :D Field was an 'int'. When I changed field to Integer it works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

`th:placeholder="your text"`